# .exe file has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++

I am writing a list-based multi-stack program. At first everything worked fine. Then I added a few exceptions. After that, the program began to build normally, but after throwing an exception, the program breaks. I opened the debugger and reached the place of error. There I found a place where another exception is thrown. But all that was written there is "MultiListStack.exe has triggered a breakpoint.". Please tell me, because of what it can be and how to fix it? Below I attach the code:

tmultiroot.h

```
//tmultiroot.h
//base abstract class for inheritance

#ifndef __MULTROOT_H__
#define __MULTROOT_H__

const int MemLimit = 4; // memory size
const int StackNum = 2;  // number of stacks

typedef int TElem; // type of element

class TMultiRoot: 
{
protected:
  TElem Mem[MemLimit]; // memory for stacks (int array of MemLimit elements)
  int DefaultStack;    // current stack number
public:
  TMultiRoot() { DefaultStack = 0; }

  virtual bool IsEmpty(int ns) const = 0; // void control
  virtual bool IsFull (int ns) const = 0; // overflow control
  virtual void Put    (int ns, const TData &Val) = 0; // put on the stack
  virtual TData Get   (int ns) = 0;       // take from stack with deletion

  // methods for working with the current stack
  void SetDefaultStack(int ns) { DefaultStack = ns; } //current stack
  int  IsEmpty(void) const     { return IsEmpty(DefaultStack); } // empty?
  int  IsFull(void) const      { return IsFull (DefaultStack); } // full of?
  void Put(const TData &Val)   { Put(DefaultStack, Val);   }     // in the stack
  TData Get(void)              { return Get(DefaultStack); }     // from the stack
};
#endif
```

multiliststack.h

```
//multiliststack.h
#ifndef __MULTILISTSTACK_H__
#define __MULTILISTSTACK_H__

#include "tmultiroot.h"

typedef int TElem; // type of element

class TMultiListStack: public TMultiRoot
{
protected:
  int NextLink[MemLimit];              // next link index
  int StackInd[StackNum];              // stack top index
  int FirstFreeLink;                   // first free link index
public:
  TMultiListStack();
  virtual bool IsEmpty(int ns) const;  // void control
  virtual bool IsFull (int ns) const;  // overflow control
  virtual void Put    (int ns, const TData &Val); // put on the stack
  virtual TData Get   (int ns);        // take from stack with deletion
// utility methods
  void Print();                // print stack values
  int  IsValid() { return 0; } // structure testing
};
#endif
```

exceptions.h

```
//exceptions.h

#ifndef _exceptions_h
#define _exceptions_h

//Exception class
class Exception{

protected:

    int Line;
    char* File;
    char* Func;
    char* Desc;

public:

    Exception() {};//default constructor
    Exception(int _Line, char* _File, char* _Func, char* _Desc); //constructor
    Exception(const Exception& e); //copy constructor
    ~Exception(); //destructor
     virtual void debug_print(); //display error message

     virtual char* GetDesc(); //return error message
};

//stack exception class
class StackExc: public Exception {

protected:

    int exc;//exception code, 0 - nomem, 1 - empty, 2 - full

public:

    StackExc() {};//default constructor
    StackExc(int _Line, char* _File, char* _Func, char* _Desc, int exc); //constructor
    StackExc::~StackExc(); //destructor
    int GetExc(); //get exception code
    virtual void debug_print(); //display error message
};

#endif
```

ecxeptions.cpp

```
//exceptions.cpp

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include "exceptions.h"

//Exception class

Exception::Exception(int _Line, char* _File, char* _Func, char* _Desc) {
    Line = _Line;
    int size = strlen(_File) + 1;  
    File = new char[size];
    strcpy(File, _File);
    Func = new char[size];
    strcpy(Func, _Func);
    Desc = new char[size];
    strcpy(Desc, _Desc);
}

//copy constructor
Exception::Exception(const Exception& e) {
    Line = e.Line;
    int size = strlen(e.File) + 1;
    File = new char[size];
    strcpy(File, e.File);
    Func = new char[size];
    strcpy(Func, e.Func);
    Desc = new char[size];
    strcpy(Desc, e.Desc);
}

//destructor
Exception::~Exception() {
    delete[] File;
    delete[] Func;
    delete[] Desc;
}

//display exception
void Exception::debug_print() {
    std::cerr << Line << " " << File << " " << Func << " " << Desc << std::endl;
}

char * Exception::GetDesc()
{
    return Desc;
}

//stack exception class

StackExc::StackExc(int _Line, char* _File, char* _Func, char* _Desc, int exc) 
    : Exception(_Line, _File, _Func, _Desc), exc(exc) {

}

//destructor
StackExc::~StackExc() {
    delete[] File;
    delete[] Func;
    delete[] Desc;
}

int StackExc::GetExc() {
    return exc;
}

//display exception
void StackExc::debug_print() {
    std::cerr << Desc << std::endl;
}
```

multiliststack.cpp

```
//multiliststack.cpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include "tmultiliststack.h"
#include "exceptions.cpp"

TMultiListStack::TMultiListStack()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MemLimit; i++)
        NextLink[i] = i + 1;
    NextLink[MemLimit - 1] = -1;
    FirstFreeLink = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < StackNum; i++)
        StackInd[i] = -1;
} 

bool TMultiListStack::IsEmpty(int ns) const // void control
{
    return StackInd[ns] < 0;
} 

bool TMultiListStack::IsFull(int ns) const // overflow control
{
    return FirstFreeLink < 0;
} 

void TMultiListStack::Put(int ns, const TData &Val) // put on the stack
{
    if (IsFull(ns)) {
        throw StackExc(__LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, "DataFull", 2); //after throwing this exception
    }                                                                    //it is being processed in main 
    else // And then an exception "MultiListStack.exe has triggered a breakpoint." occurs on this line
    {
        int k = FirstFreeLink;
        FirstFreeLink = NextLink[k];
        Mem[k] = Val;
        NextLink[k] = StackInd[ns];
        StackInd[ns] = k;
    }
} 

TData TMultiListStack::Get(int ns) // take from stack with deletion
{
    TData temp = -1;                                                  
    if (IsEmpty(ns))
        throw StackExc(__LINE__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, "DataEmpty", 1);
    else
    {
        int k = StackInd[ns];
        temp = Mem[k];
        StackInd[ns] = NextLink[k];
        NextLink[k] = FirstFreeLink;
        FirstFreeLink = k;
    }
    return temp;                                                      
}

void TMultiListStack::Print() // print stack values
{
    int pind, ind, k;
    for (int ns = 0; ns < StackNum; ns++)
    {
        printf("ns=%d -> ", ns);
        pind = -1;
        ind = StackInd[ns];
        while (ind > -1) // pointer wrapping
        {
            k = NextLink[ind];
            NextLink[ind] = pind;
            pind = ind;
            ind = k;
        }
        ind = pind;
        pind = -1;
        while (ind > -1) // pointer recovery and printing
        {
            printf("%d ", Mem[ind]);
            k = NextLink[ind];
            NextLink[ind] = pind;
            pind = ind;
            ind = k;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "tmultiliststack.h"

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    TMultiListStack mst;
    int ms = 2, ns, code, temp, val = 0;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    srand(1);
    cout << "System Testing N Stacks" << endl;

    while (1)
    {
        try {
            val++;
            code = random(4);    // operation
            ns = random(ms);   // stack number
            Sleep(1000);
            if (code < 3) {
                cout << "Put " << val << " in " << ns << endl;
                mst.Put(ns, val);
                mst.Print();
            }
            else {
                cout << "Get from " << ns << endl;
                temp = mst.Get(ns);
                mst.Print();
            }
        }
        catch (StackExc exc) {
            exc.debug_print();
        }
        if (_kbhit())
            break;
    }
    cout << "Stack Printing" << endl;
    mst.Print();
}
```

When the program starts, 4 values ​​are put on the zero stack. But at the fifth iteration, when the fifth value is to be added to the zero stack, overflow occurs. Because of this, my exception is thrown. Then it is processed in main. And after that, this incomprehensible exception is thrown. No details about it are displayed, so I don’t understand what to do. Tell me, please, how to fix it?

Comment: I found this great article for you: http://peterforgacs.github.io/2017/06/25/Custom-C-Exceptions-For-Beginners/

Comment: That is not how you make exceptions in C++ at all.

Comment: @BaileyKocin What is the fundamental difference? That I do not inherit my exceptions from standard?

Comment: Scratch what i said. I didnt know you could throw any type. My bad. Anyways you catch the object by value and not reference.

Comment: Are you sure you are allocating the right amount of memory for each string in your Exception constructor?